# Django and Ajax/Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, forms

I have the following model layout:

```
class A(models.model):
    options = models.ManyToManyField(OptionSet, blank=True, null=True)
    values = models.ManyToManyField(Value, blank=True, null=True)

class OptionSet(models.model):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)
    values = models.ManyToManyField(Value)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

class Value(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    key = models.ForeignKey(Key, related_name='values')

class Key(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(unique=True)
```

And my forms.py looks like this:

```
class A_Form(ModelForm):
    values = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Value.objects.all(), widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, label="Einzelne Werte", required=False)
    options = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=OptionSet.objects.all(), widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, label="Optionen Sets", required=False)
```

Template:

```
<form action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update"/> 
</form>
```

I use that form with a generic update view!
I'm new to javascript/ajax to be honest never did something in javascript/ajax. What I want to do is on mouseover on the options name it should show all the values for that option set. How would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery's .post() method to send the name of the active option to django script(actually url on server).Then you can find out all the values using queries(I'm assuming you already know how to extract data from models).Then again you can use HttpResponse() to send the calculated values list back to your page.

Comment: Sorry for asking and thanks for your answer however isn't that too complicated?

Comment: If you know a simpler answer then yes. In this case, please share your simpler answer wagner-felix. Otherwise, no

Comment: yeah i know that's somewhat complicated if you've never programmed jquery and sql before

Comment: It's not that I dont understand  I just thought It would be simpler, well thanks anyway